# django-mssql: 'Query timeout expired' during syncdb

Tags: sql-server, django, constraints, django-mssql

After `syncdb` creates the tables I get an error when enabling the constraints:

```
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
DatabaseError: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft SQL Server N
ative Client 10.0', u'Query timeout expired', None, 0, -2147217871), None)
Command:
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
Parameters:
[]
```

But when running the below command manually against the same database after the tables have been created, it runs without errors:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

The database contains hundreds of tables that are not generated by Django itself. Running syncdb against an empty MSSQL database does not produce this error. Could this be a timeout caused by too many tables in the database? If so, would I resolve it? I'm using the `django-mssql` drivers.

Comment: The "WITH CHECK" can be a slow operation for large databases. Part of syncdb disables foreign keys and later re-enables them. After they are re-enabled, the tables need to be checked to make sure bad data didn't get a chance to slip in without being noticed. How long does the command take when run manually? You'll most likely need to increase the COMMAND_TIMEOUT as answered by @krescruz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change parameter COMMAND_TIMEOUT in config database Setting.py Example:

```
'COMMAND_TIMEOUT': Numberseconds
```